# The control type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' cannot be themed

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are using alot of updatepanels in our webbapplication on almoste every one has `UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`.

I wanted to avoid this so i created a `/App_Themes/Standard/Standard.skin` file and added `<pages theme="Standard">` to the web.config file but now i get the following error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The control type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel'
>   cannot be themed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 18:  Line 19:
>   
>   Line 20:  Line 21:
>
> Source File:  /App_Themes/Standard/Standard.skin    Line:  20
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446

Dose any one know why the UpdatePanel can't be themed and it there is a workaround?

Comment: Standard.skin consist of one line `<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

Skin files are meant to be used to apply a consistent look and feel to an application. Since an UpdatePanel results in no UI of its own, it is not a valid control for specification in a Skin file. Hope that helps and here's a MS article that may help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ykzx33wh(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well the update panel has one property that does affect the look and feel :) RenderMode, also the control has a property named EnableTheming that suggests that some sort of theming is involved?